# Creating XML with Haml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, haml, sitemap

I'm trying to make a dynamic sitemap for my CMS-style rails app, but I am having trouble creating a sitemap in XML using Haml. I looked at the docs and they say that I should be able to use `!!! XML` to insert the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` tag at the beginning of the document. When I try to do this, it does not render anything at all and I am forced to use a literal meta-xml tag. What am I doing wrong?

```
content_controller.rb
=====================
class ContentController < ApplicationController
  # other methods

  def sitemap
    @sections = Section.all :include => :pages
    respond_to do |format|
      format.xml
    end
  end
end

sitemap.xml.haml
================
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-# !!! XML
-# the above tag does not work
%urlset{:xmlns => 'http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9'}
  %url
    %loc= root_url
  - @sections.each do |section|
    - section.pages.each do |page|
      %url
        %loc= "#{root_url}#{section.url}/#{page.url}"
        %lastmod= page.updated_at
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to set `:format => :xhtml` in order for this to work.
In your `environment.rb`

```
Haml::Template.options[:format] = :xhtml
```

More info here http://www.mail-archive.com/haml@googlegroups.com/msg06984.html

Comment: One alternative is to place this configuration into a proper initializer, just like suggested in this [blog post](http://www.mindgravy.net/2010/10/15/using-other-doctypes-with-haml-and-rails-3/).